# VS Code: How to make Regex Option in search pre-selected

Tags: search, visual-studio-code

Everytime I search in VS Code the regex button is not selected. This often yields in me wondering, why nothing has been found.

Is there a way, that this button is selected by default, so that I don't have to activate it manually everytime?

Comment: It will remember its selection state between opening and closing the find widget or closing vscode.  Are you referring to find in a file or search across files?

Comment: I meant all search dialogs in general. I found a setting, that vs code remembers, the settings I made for next time. (It's not exactly what I was looking for, but better, that it is now.) I'm just trying it out, I will post a solution, if this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this setting: Features » Search » "Search Editor: Reuse Prior Search Configuration"

Instead of configuring default values, the search dialogue basically remembers the last used settings. It has the drawback, that you have to remember to reset the defaults, after a search with different settings. But it’s still better, than to have to have to set up the default values everytime before a search.